# Two conditions in single line for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I have a function that has a `return` statement as follows:

```
x = 0
return{
    'restaurantList' : [restaurant.serializeGeneral(myArray[x]) for restaurant in self.restaurantList],
    'success' : self.success
    }
```

I need to increment `x` every time the `for` loop runs, however, I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: Can you show the actual function? There might be a better way to design your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to get both the index and value for each restaurant in the list as follows:

```
return {
    'restaurantList' : [restaurant.serializeGeneral(myArray[x]) for x, restaurant in enumerate(self.restaurantList)],
    'success' : self.success
}
```

You should probably just compute the list outside of a list comprehension because that line is way too long to be readable.